# ТурБюро; наследование, пакеты, интерфейсы (Java)

Tags: java

Помогите в теме inheritance, packages & interfaces.

[image: UML]
<sub>(источник: [fotos-hochladen.net](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/untitledjqp4n3bzwv.jpg))</sub>

Турбюро(`TuiReisen`) организует поездки на всего одном поезде(`Bahn`) и одном автобусе(`Bus`) для пассажиров(`Kunde`), кот.  могут быть как простые персоны(`Privatperson`) с именем и фамилией, так и студенты(`Studenten`) c Ф.И. + названием вуза.

Я не могу сообразить, как в этих методах :

```
public boolean бронировать(Пассажир k, int transport) 

и

public boolean бронировать(Пассажир[] группа, int transport)
// transport→АВТОБУС(1), ПОЕЗД(2), БЕЗРАЗЛИЧНО (0)
```

проверить наличие мест, в выбранном пассажирами транспорте и произвести бронировку(т.е. каждому пассажиру по одному/свободному месту), чтобы в последующих методах, через метод в классе `Пассажир.получиCообщение(String)` вывести на консоль сообщение каждому отдельному пассажиру о том, что место на автобусе или поезде было забронировано, либо же нет итд.

Main/Test выглядит так:

```
 //создать автобус, кот.имеет ср. скорость 80,5 км/ч и 3 места в наличии
 Bus bus = new Bus(80.5,3);
 //создать поезд, кот.имеет ср. скорость 120 км/ч и 10 мест в наличии
 Bahn bahn = new Bahn(120,10);

//создать филиал TuiReisen, кот. Заправляет местами вышеук. bus и bahn 
TuiReisen tui1 = new TuiReisen(bus, bahn);

//создать персону как пассажира
Kunde p1 = new Privatperson("Вера", "Ростова");

//создать студента как пассажира
Student s1 = new Student("Наташа", "Ростова", "МГУ");
Student s2 = new Student("Андрей", "Болконский", "МИРЭА");
Student s3 = new Student("Анатолий", "Курагин", "МИЭМ");

//вызов метода бронировкуПодтвердить(Пассажир п, int transport)
tui1.buchungBestaetigen(s2, 2);
//Консоль ожидает, например:
Андрей Болконский, МИРЭА: Место на поезде для Вас забронировано!
```

Comment: Наверное в TuiReisen» автобусы и поезда стоит реализовать как массивы и тогда проверка брони будет с лёгкостью решена.

Comment: Аrik, это уже тоже пробовала)) Только как совместить int array с местами в траспорте с массивом, кот. ссылается на объекты типа пассажир? P.S.: Прошу не судить строго, это моя 5-я программа.

Comment: Arik, я ниже в комменте для LetitRock описала требования к стуктуре программы... интерфейсы нам были даны, к огромному сожалению((

Comment: Вот как вместить в методы: места в поезде  и автобусе + пассажиров + в зависимости от постоянных (поезд, автобус, безразлично -> возможность выбора транспорта для пассажиров) не допру(((

Comment: А разве «анзахлБусПлац» - это не общее количество мест в автобусе? Если так, то можно при каждом добавлении пассажиров его уменьшать.

Comment: да,  поезд(колличество мест, средняя скорость) и автобус(колличество мест, средняя скорость), а также пассажиры поездов и автобусов, кот. могут быть студенты или персоны... в таком колличестве переменных уже потерялась)))))))

Comment: Так значит всё в порядке и проблема решена?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать класс абстрактный транспортное средство (ТС), у которого был бы идентификатор (ID), который нужно указать через конструктор... а также метод абстрактный... каждый клас наследуемый по ТС должен указать ID... и реализовать метод нп. возвращающий текст нп. "Место на поезде для Вас забронировано!"... тогда метод buchungBestaetigen мог бы принимать пасажира + ID-ТС по которому внутри бы искал  ТС и вызывать реализацию абстрактного метода.

```
public abstract class AbstractTransportmittel {

private Long id;

public AbstractTransportmittel(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public abstract String nachricht();

}
```

реализация buchungBestaetigen:

```
public String buchungBestaetigen(AbstractTransportmittel ts, Long id){
    for(AbstractTransportmittel ts: array){
        if(ts.getId().equals(id)){
            return ts.nachricht();
        }
    }
    return "тс не найдено!!!";
}
```

Comment: LetitRock, огромное спасибо за вариант! :-) Я на нем обязательно поучусь, только вот пунктов мне за это проф не даст, т.к. должна быть сохранена ею данная структура, а именно: `1-й package: interface пассажир, class персона implements пассажир, class студент extends персона; 2-й package: interface транспорт, class автобус implements транспорт, class поезд implements транспорт; 3-й пакет: interface турбюро, TuiReisen implements турбюро`; и из `4-го default package` нужно вызывать `Main `; Причем `параметры методов TuiReisen (Пассажир п, int транспорт)` -> никак не допру, как все вместить(((

Comment: в интерфейсе транспорт (Transportmittel) добавьте два метода: public Long getId(); и public String nachricht(); и заимплементируйте их реализацию в классах поезд и автобус... метод buchungBestaetigen будет выглядеть так: public String buchungBestaetigen(Transportmittel ts, Long id){
    for(Transportmittel ts: array){
        if(ts.getId().equals(id)){
            return ts.nachricht();
        }
    }
    return "тс не найдено!!!";
}